# checkbox function not working for dropdown menu

Tags: css, html

I have created a dropdown menu that shows when a checkbox is clicked.

It works perfectly outside of wordpress see JS Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/s7w2ueah/

however when I add it into my WP theme ( running blankslate ) the checkbox function does not work ( I assume it is the checkbox function) - I have run it on a number of different themes to no avail which makes me think that this is a problem on all wordpress themes.

I have an example of it here on an existing website running wordpress twenty fourteen.

How can I make the menu drop down ?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [`wp_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) function the default classes are like below:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">SubMenu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SubMenu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
</ul>
```

Note that, the `.menu` and `.sub-menu`. May be you are messing with the wrong `class` names, and some `class` conflicts.